# Please identify this black 2x2 tile with sticker, sunset with 2 palm trees and boat

Tags: part-identification, set-identification

Can someone identify the set origin of this sticker on a black 2x2 tile?

[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is part #  [3068bpb0183 : Tile 2 x 2 with Hovercraft Sunset Pattern (Sticker)](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=3068bpb0183#T=C&C=11)

From [8485-1: Control Centre II](https://brickset.com/sets/8485-1/Control-Centre-II)

[image]